# Evaluate $c\sum_{k \geq 0} e^{kn}e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $Z$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{P}(Z=e^k)=ce^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$ where $c=\sum_{k \geq 0}e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$.

How can I compute $\mathbb{E}[Z^n]=c\sum_{k \geq 0} e^{kn}e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$?

Comment: Is $$\mathbb{E}[Z^n]=ce^{n^2/2}\left(c+\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-k^2/2}\right)$$ a satisfactory answer? To obtain this result, try completing the square.